# Deregister style.css in WordPress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, stylesheet

Does anyone know if it's possible to deregister the default stylesheet of a theme, style.css, in WordPress? I've tried going wp_deregister_style('style') and wp_deregister_style('style.css'), but neither seems to work.

I'm hoping to do this so I can optimise my site my combining my various stylesheets into one and minifying it with an Ant script.

Comment: Is you goal to just use another stylesheet? You can have multiple stylesheets show up in the online editor just by adding the header comments at the top of the .css file.

Comment: matthewvb, the aim is to reduce the number of stylesheets I include to one - it helps with page loading.

Comment: Okay. How about excluding the default stylesheet in your <head> from being imported?

Comment: OK thanks matthewvb, I guess I misunderstood how it works. So when creating a theme you need to either include style.css in the page header, or do it with wp_register_style() and wp_enqueue_style() in your functions.php. In the former case, you could manage the stylesheet inclusion in header.php; in the latter case the stylesheet would be accessible via whatever handle you gave it in wp_register_style(), and you could deregister it that way. I assumed WordPress included style.css in the page automatically, like it does with jQuery. Stupid question! Thanks for putting me right.

Comment: Side note: w3 total cache has css minification build in: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/

Comment: Thanks janw.. we had problems with one of those optimisation plugins so were doing it the long way round.

Answer (score 5):

According to Wordpress behavior, which requires to pass a handle when registering and de-registering a stylesheet, and as the default stylesheet "style.css" is registered with the handle "screen", we should use this code :

```
wp_dequeue_style('screen');
wp_deregister_style('screen');
```